# Ruby - Returning LATEST condition matched, not first condition matched

Tags: ruby, if-statement, switch-statement, boolean, conditional-statements

Hypothetical case statement below that takes into account three variables:

- name
- age
- garlic_allergy

With the case statement below, the goal is to have the "result" variable update to the LATEST condition, rather than the first condition match. e.g. If the user were to input variables age=90, garlic_allergy=false, name=Dracula, the case statement should return "Definitely a vampire" (the LATEST condition met) as opposed to "Probably NOT a vampire" (the first condition met).

```
    case
    when age.to_i < 100 && garlic_allergy = false
      result = "Probably NOT a vampire"
    when age.to_i < 100 && garlic_allergy = true 
      result = "Maybe a vampire"
    when age.to_i > 100 && garlic_allergy = true
      result = "almost certainly a vampire"
    when name = "Dracula"
      result = "Definitely a vampire"
    else
      result = "Results inconclusive"  
    end

    puts result
    end
```

This is an example case, but trying to figure out how to do this for any case statement or if/elsif/else statement with multiple conditions, etc. ... how to make sure the program runs through every when/elsif statement and returns the latest condition. I tried doing it by wrapping the statement in a loop but haven't had any luck yet.

Answer (score 0):

Build an array with your conditions

```
conditions = []

conditions.push lambda { |name, age, garlic_allergy|
  'Probably NOT a vampire' if age < 100 and not garlic_allergy
}

conditions.push lambda { |name, age, garlic_allergy| 
  'Maybe a vampire' if age < 100 and garlic_allergy
}

conditions.push lambda { |name, age, garlic_allergy|
  'almost certainly a vampire' if age > 100 and garlic_allergy
}

conditions.push lambda { |name, age, garlic_allergy|
  'Definitely a vampire' if name == 'Dracula'
}
```

And reduce your conditions to the last succeeded one.

```
result = conditions.inject('Results inconclusive') { |current, x|
  r = x.(name, age, garlic_allergy)

  r != nil ? r : current
}
```

Note that the initial value of `inject` is the fallback condition, which will be kept in case none condition succeed.